# MySQL: обнуление дублирующихся записей, кроме самой первой

Tags: mysql

Вопрос по MySQL, 
есть таблица вида:

```
id       int(10) PRIMARY KEY
name     VarChar(50)
```

Задача при совпадении поля `name` удалить его значение! у всех кроме первого.

т.е. выбрать записи у которых `name` встречается более 1 раза, и у всех кроме наименшего `id`, поле `name` обнулить.. есть способы? за 1 запрос....?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

В MySQL, к сожалению, такую задачу одним запросом решить не получится. Однако есть способ, использующий промежуточную таблицу.
Можно сделать, например, так:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp AS
  SELECT MIN(id) id
  FROM table
  GROUP BY name;
UPDATE table SET name = null WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM temp);
```

Либо с использованием Вашего любимого языка программирования выполнить запрос

```
  SELECT MIN(id) id
  FROM table
  GROUP BY name;
```

И подставить результат его выполнения в UPDATE.

**UPD>** Небольшое пояснение к запросу - он выбирает ID записей с, так сказать, уникальными NAME. Поэтому в дальнейшем запросе не обновление и используется NOT IN. Мы обновляем записи, которые не вошли в этот список.

Comment: Несовсем понимаю второй запрос, если не сложно обьясните по русски что оно мне выберет(не в курсе что есть HAVING, и не понял сей момент MIN(id) id, тут и в правду нет запятой?). Сейчас реализовано несколькими запросами + обработкой на "моём любимом языке". 1) идет выборка всех дублей, далее на любимом языке, удаляется минимальный айди для каждого уникального имени, и результат подставляется в Update в виде массива.

Comment: @_rMx а так разве не катит ?(я правда не уверен а проверять лень)

    UPDATE table SET name = null WHERE id NOT IN 
     (SELECT MIN(id) id
       FROM table
       GROUP BY name
       HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      );

по идее вложенный селект как раз создает временную таблицу

Comment: @eicto Я проверил, мой MySQL 5.5 ругнулся на то, что нельзя использовать обновляемую таблицу в WHERE.
@ToRcH565 MIN(id) id равнозначно записи MIN(id) AS id. С HAVING обманул, обновил ответ. Писал ночью, мозг шуршал с трудом ))

Comment: Having обманул MySQL или тебя ? :) Проверь, заапдейтились только нужные данные ?

Comment: Добрался до потестить) ваши варианты выдают обратный результат) мне не нужно узнавать минимальный айди, мне нужно узнать все айди кроме минимального! и обнулить там поле name.

Comment: Пока этот монстр трудится...    

    SELECT (user_id) 
      id,
      nick
    FROM 
      users a
    where 
     (select count(nick) from users b where b.nick=a.nick)>1 and
     (select min(user_id) from users b where b.nick=a.nick)<>user_id

Answer (score 0):

Можно полностью удалить такие записи при помощи запроса

```
DELETE
  d
FROM
  `tbl` AS d
JOIN
  (SELECT
    name,
    MIN(id) AS minid
  FROM
    `tbl`
  GROUP BY
    name
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1) AS dbl
ON
  d.name = dbl.name AND d.id > dbl.minid
```

Если нужно занулить лишь значение `name` для дублей, можно воспользоваться следующим UPDATE-запросом

```
UPDATE
  tbl
JOIN
  (SELECT
    name,
    MIN(id) AS minid
  FROM
    tbl
  GROUP BY
    name
  HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 1) AS dbl
ON
  tbl.name = dbl.name AND tbl.id > dbl.minid
SET
  tbl.name = ''
```